# Why FindRoot fail in this case?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a set of equations:

$$\frac{\epsilon+(k(1-N)+2\beta)\upsilon_l-\epsilon \upsilon_l^2-2\Omega(1-N)\upsilon_l^3}{-\Omega\upsilon_l^4+k\upsilon_l^2-\Omega}=\sum_{j\neq l}^N\frac{2}{\upsilon_j-\upsilon_l}$$

where all the parameters are real. Using the solutions of these equations I can calculate the quantity

$$E=\frac{k N^2}{4}+\frac{\beta N}{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\sum_{j=1}^N\upsilon_j-\Omega\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\sum_{l=j+1}^N\upsilon_j\upsilon_l$$
Once the solutions are unique, each set of solution give only one value of $E$, and I can check this value by other methods. So I wrote:

Equations:

```
ν[Npart_] := Table[Symbol["ν" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, Npart}];
u[Npart_, j_] := ν[Npart][[j]];
BAE[Npart_, k_, β_, ϵ_, Ω_] := 
  SetPrecision[
   ParallelTable[(-ϵ (u[Npart, l])^2)/(
      k (u[Npart, l])^2 - Ω (u[Npart, 
          l])^4 - Ω) + ϵ/(
      k (u[Npart, l])^2 - Ω (u[Npart, 
          l])^4 - Ω) + ((k (1 - Npart) + 2 β) u[
        Npart, l])/(
      k (u[Npart, l])^2 - Ω (u[Npart, 
          l])^4 - Ω) + (-2 Ω (1 - 
         Npart) (u[Npart, l])^3)/(
      k (u[Npart, l])^2 - Ω (u[Npart, 
          l])^4 - Ω) == 
     Sum[2/(u[Npart, j] - u[Npart, l]), {j, 
       Complement[Range[Npart], {l}]}], {l, 1, Npart}], 200];
```

Solutions:

```
BAEroots[Npart_, k_, β_, ϵ_, Ω_] := 
 FindRoot[BAE[Npart, k, β, ϵ, Ω], 
  Table[{u[Npart, j], 0.05 + (j - 1)/Npart}, {j, 1, Npart}], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 200, AccuracyGoal -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 100, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Routine:

```
NewRoots[Npart_, k_, β_, ϵ_, initial_, final_] := 
 Block[{SP = BAEroots[Npart, k, β, ϵ, 0]},
  Do[NSP = 
    FindRoot[BAE[Npart, k, β, ϵ, i], 
     Table[{u[Npart, j], u[Npart, j] /. SP}, {j, 1, Npart}], 
     WorkingPrecision -> 200, AccuracyGoal -> 100, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 100, MaxIterations -> 1000];
   Print["***********************************************************\
"];
   Print["Ω = ", N[i], " \[Rule] ", "γ = ", 
    N[(Npart i)/ϵ]];
   Print["roots : ", SetPrecision[NSP, 20]];
   Print["Energy : ", 
    SetPrecision[((k Npart^2)/4 + (β Npart)/
        2 + -ϵ/2 Sum[u[Npart, j], {j, 1, Npart}] - 
        i Sum[u[Npart, j] u[Npart, l], {j, 1, Npart - 1}, {l, j + 1, 
           Npart}]) /. NSP, 20]];
   SP = NSP, {i, initial, final, (final - initial)/10}]]
```

The solutions are very sensitive to the initial conditions, and there was a few cases where `BAEroots` worked. So I wrote a routine that vary the parameter $\Omega$ in small steps and take the previous solution as a starting point to next. I know that all roots must be real and positive.

Everything works well, but a some point FindRoot fail. For example, If I set `N=4, k=0.5, \beta=0,\epsilon=1` and `inicial = 0`, `final=-0.25`,

[image]

I tried raise the number of interactions, the working precision, etc... and nothing worked. Have you guys any ideia why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Give your code in copy-able format. It is too much typing otherwise.