# Updating the initial guess by using the previous solution

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Consider the following equation:

$$
 \frac{1}{y^2 - 0.3x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} = 1
 $$

I am required to solve for $y$ for a list of $x$ values, between 0 and 1, using `FindRoot`, see below.

```
f[y_, x_] := 1/(y^2 - 0.3*x^2) - 1/x^2 ;
    
y0 = -1.14*10^-8 + 0 I;
    
Do[Print[{i, FindRoot[f[y, i] == 1, {y, y0}]}], {i, 10^-8, 1, 0.1}]
```

In the code, `y0` is an initial guess or the starting value. I have started at an $x$-value very close zero, $x = 10^{-8}$.

The output/solutions:

```
{10^-8, {y-> -1.14018*10^-8}}
{0.1, {y-> -0.113583}}
{0.2, {y-> 0.224636}}
{0.3, {y-> -0.331012}}
{0.4, {y-> -0.431197}}
{0.5, {y-> -0.524404}}
{0.6, {y-> -0.610496}}
{0.7, {y-> 0.689825}}
{0.8, {y-> 0.763049}}
{0.9,{y-> -0.830972}}
```

Most of the roots/solutions, the y-values, are correct, but some are not. For example, at $x = 0.8$, the corresponding solution is $y = 0.763049$, which is not correct. The correct solution at that $x$-value is $y = -0.763049$. In fact, all the roots are supposed to be negative.

What I am trying to accomplish:

(i) Give an initial guess for $y$. In this case at $x = 10^{-8}$.

(ii) Update `y0` by using the previous solution of the previous $x$-value since it would be the closest guess. For example to solve for $y$ at $x = 0.4$, the initial guess would the solution at $x = 0.3$.

(iii) Accomplish step (ii) by using a loop for $x$ between 0 and 1.

Is there a way of updating the initial guess by using the previous solution of the previous $x$-value?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you required to solve it by this approach (is it part of some homework exercise)? If not, you can replace ``FindRoot`` with ``NSolve[f[y, i] == 1 && y < 0, y]``. Also, take a look at the plot: ``Plot3D[{f[y, x], 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`` to see that there are multiple "branches" of solutions, and ``FindRoot`` can sometimes jump to the other one.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10592/using-previous-two-solutions-as-a-start-point-in-findroot, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54601/backsubstituting-solution-into-findroot-and-plot; https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99759/why-findroot-fail-in-this-case

Comment: It's a nice example for this sort of exercise, given how the singularity moves as `x`/`i` increases.

Comment: @Domen, thank you for your suggestion. We are required to use an initial/starting value, so I will need to use 'FindRoot'.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to plug in the last solution value:

```
Rest@FoldList[
  Function[{ysol, i},
   {i, FindRoot[f[y, i] == 1, {y, y /. Last@ysol}]}
   ],
  {"Start", y -> y0},
  Range[10^-8, 1, 0.1]]
(*
{{1.*10^-8, {y -> -1.14018*10^-8}},
 {0.1, {y -> -0.113583}},
 {0.2, {y -> -0.224636}},
 {0.3, {y -> -0.331012}},
 {0.4, {y -> -0.431197}},
 {0.5, {y -> -0.524404}},
 {0.6, {y -> -0.610496}},
 {0.7, {y -> -0.689825}},
 {0.8, {y -> -0.763049}},
 {0.9, {y -> -0.830972}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

A better approach that gives more accurate results is to solve the equation analytically:

```
f[y_, x_] := 1/(y^2 - 3/10*x^2) - 1/x^2
rule = Solve[{f[y, x] == 1, y < 0}, y, Reals][[1]] ;
res = Table[{x, y} /. rule, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // N

(* {{0., 0.}, {0.1, -0.113583}, {0.2, -0.224636}, {0.3, -0.331012}, \
{0.4, -0.431197}, {0.5, -0.524404}, {0.6, -0.610496}, {0.7, \
-0.689825}, {0.8, -0.763049}, {0.9, -0.830972}, {1., -0.894427}} *)
```

To check (with the excpetion x==0):

```
(f[#[[2]], #[[1]]]) & /@ Rest@res

(*{1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Table` for this kind of thing:

```
y\[Prime] = -1.14*10^-8;(* initialize old result *)

res = Table[
  y = (y /. FindRoot[f[y, x] == 1, {y, y\[Prime]}][[1]]);
  y\[Prime] = y; (* update old result *)
  {x, y}
, {x, 10^-8, 1, 0.1}]
```

It's overkill for this problem, but this version uses linear extrapolation from the last two points to get a better initial guess:

```
y\[Prime]\[Prime] = y\[Prime] = -1.14*10^-8;(* initialize older and old results *)

res = Table[
  y = (y /. FindRoot[f[y, x] == 1, {y, 2 y\[Prime] - y\[Prime]\[Prime]}][[1]]);
  (* update older and old results *)
  y\[Prime]\[Prime] = y\[Prime]; y\[Prime] = y;
  {x, y}
, {x, 10^-8, 1, 0.1}]
```